# jquery change text of anchor link

Tags: jquery, html

I have this anchor link:

```
<li><a class="tab" id="watchTicket" href="#" onclick="CallPage('/section/tickets/view-ticket?action=watch&seq=<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>');"><?php echo ($TicketWatched ? 'Un-Watch' : 'Watch'); ?></a></li>
```

i want to be able to change the text inside it using jquery, i have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a#watchTicket").text('Watch');
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("li a#watchTicket").text('Watch');
</script>
```

but neither are changing the text, and no errors are in the console

i have this jquery function:

```
function CallPage(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
}
```

that calls a page, this is the function used in the anchor `OnClick`

all of this code is on a single page, and i change the text at the top of the page - that is using PHP and JQuery:

```
<?php
if($_GET["action"] == 'watch' && isset($_GET["seq"])) {
    // SQL Query here
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a#watchTicket").text('Watch');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

then the actual anchor link is below this code

**UPDATE**

i have just changed my function to:

```
function WatchTicket() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'view-ticket?seq=<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>&action=watch',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            var text = $("a#watchTicket").text();

            if(text === "Watch") {
                $("a#watchTicket").text('Un-Watch');
            } else {
                $("a#watchTicket").text('Watch');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

which i call in the `OnClick` of the anchor tag

but now this isnt changing the text although the call is successful?

Comment: This script, as is, should be changing the elements text unless it's running before the HTML. Try wrapping it inside `$(document).ready`

Comment: why are you setting type as jsonp?

Comment: try changing `a#watchTicket` to `#watchTicket` and check there isn't any other element with the same id. If nothing happens, try with an alert() to watch if the js runs inside the `if{}else{}` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jQuery code doesn't work for unknown reason you could try with javascript.

```
function WatchTicket() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'view-ticket?seq=<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>&action=watch',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            var link_node = document.getElementById('watchTicket');
            var txt = "Watch";
            link_node.innerHTML = link_node.innerHTML === txt ? 'Un-Watch' : txt;


        }
    });
}
```

If it doesn't work it's beacuse the Ajax request fails probably.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Try wrapping it with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

UPDATE:

You should put `$("a#watchTicket").text('Watch');` and any relevant code in the success callback, so when the ajax call finished successfully, it updates the anchor text.

Comment: Maybe check the final html output? this should be working, check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ox9wqvj2/

Comment: check my update - i didnt think this would have made a different but maybe it does?

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly, but, are you trying to update the anchor text once the ajax call has finished (which url is the same page)?

Comment: check my latest update - have created a seperate function for it

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `<script>` tag outside the `if($_GET["action"] == 'watch' && isset($_GET["seq"])) { ... }` php tag.

If the page is a php with:

```
<a id="watchTicket" ... ></a> //your link
<?php if(){ ...} ?> //the php code
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("a#watchTicket").text('Watch');
 });
<script>
```

And make sure jQuery is loading correctly. The code should work.

Edit:

If you want to occur after 'callPage' is loaded, put your:  `$("a#watchTicket").text('Watch');` inside the `success: function(data){` part.